# Multiple modules with name are being created and they will overwrite each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When trying to run an angular project, just a black page is displayed. On debugging I see a message "Multiple modules with name are being created and they will overwrite each other."

How to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search through your codebase for `angular.module`. You shouldn't have `angular.module('someName',[])` more than once for the same module.

Passing in the second argument for the modules it requires is for instantiation/creation. Whereas `angular.module('foo')` can be repeated cause that simply tries to retrieve a module that has already been created.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was able to debug. Cheers!!